# Generating unique identification by concatenating two numbers

Tags: java

I want to generate an unique identification number for my project. I have two tables:

1. Department
2. employee_details_table

I have defined the primary key for "department" as:

```
department_id tinyint(2) zerofill not null auto_increment,
```

For "employee_details_table", the primary key is named as "employee_id".
I want to generate employee id for this column as a five digit number (or string) wherein the first two digits are the department_id that is assigned to the employee and the last 3 digits should actually be like auto_increment.

Example:

- 01020 : It should be assigned to an employee belonging to department 01 and he is the 20th employee in that dept.
- 03040 : It should be assigned to an employee belonging to department 03 and he is the 40th employee in that dept.

P.S.: I have posted this question after intensive research and trying my hand at coding the stuff.

Comment: I'm unsure that your point of view of this problem resolution is the best practice to have.

Comment: each dept will have only 999 emp?

Comment: In the employee_details_table, you create 2 columns.  Employee_id is an auto-incrementing integer and the primary key of the table.  Department_id is a foreign key back to the Department table.  You concatenate these two columns when you want to display the Employee ID,

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Thank u for ur response. But, how can I change the value of employee id after keeping it as auto-incrmenting?

Comment: Why do you want to change the employee id?  Isn't an employee id once issued always the same?

Comment: using string concatenation (or even worse decimal arithmetics) to generate combined keys is very bad practice as it does not work with the relational arithmetric. I would avoid it. Just use a department column and a employee number. In your case this is also important because you would have to renumber your keys when an employee changes department.

Comment: You mean `employee_id=department_id*1000+employee_num`

Comment: @eckes Not exactly what u r saying. It shud b : employee_id=dept_id+employee_num (It shud be integer concatenation but both the id shud not be added up. Thank u for ur response

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that an employee can change departments in a company. Thus, the primary key should not reflect the department, since an employee moving from "Information Technology" to "Management Information" would force their PK to change every where it is held in the database (it is possible to implement it like that, but considered bad practice).

Instead you should use an ordinary auto-increment PK on the `employee` table so that your joins are reliable, and then decide add a new column containing the number they are in the department.

So you'll also need this in the `employee` table:

```
department_nth tinyint(2) not null,
```

This is non-unique, so there will be one 1 for each department, one 2 for each department, etc until all departments have a sequence of 1..N for their employees.

Your employee numbers are therefore a cosmetic device: `01020` is just the `department.department_id` concatenated with the `employee.department_nth` - you do not need to explicitly store it anywhere. When referring to the employee in the database (i.e. a foreign key) just use `employee_id`, since it will not change.

It's also worth considering how a department move should affect the `department_nth` value: if "Management Information" has four employees and the first one moves to "Compliance", should the others be renumbered? Or would they stick as `2, 3, 4` with no `1`?

Comment: Thank u for ur response. Well, coming to ur question, the other employees won't be remembered. Actually, this idea of generating employee_id is my client's idea. Coming to ur answer, what would be the difference between department_id and department_nth(apart from the fact that they belong to different tables)? Is there any way I can generate the employee_id in the way I have mentioned in the question (assuming that the employees won't change their dept). Thanks, once again

Comment: The `department_id` is the unique key belonging to the department, whereas the `department_nth` is the position the employee holds within their current department (first employee = 1, second = 2, etc). This is unique per department, but not unique over all departments. Yes, if you want to use a string primary key, then you can have the primary key you are referring to. However, in no real-world situation can you assume that employees will not change department.

Comment: "Actually, this idea of generating employee_id is my client's idea" - that is generally not a good reason to do something. Unless they are involved in integrating it with another system and have some expertise in this area, use ordinary integer PKs and display the cosmetic employee number on-screen wherever you need it.

Comment: "Yes, if you want to use a string primary key, then you can have the primary key you are referring to."  Yeah, I want to use a string primary key.

Comment: Coming to ur suggestion, how can I work on department_nth; can u please elaborate it?

Comment: If you want to use the string primary key containing a department number and an Nth employee-in-dept number, you don't need `department_nth`, since the PK will already contain it.

Comment: thank u, though I still need to work on it. Thank u for editing the question as well.